# Gas oven won't maintain temperature it is set on

Tags: oven

Maytag oven initially ignites, heats up to temperature selected but won't reignite to maintain temperature.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a lot more info (what model? how old is it? when did this start happening? etc.). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because operation of major appliances is listed as off-topic on our [help page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @JPhi1618 I don't think this is **operation** of major appliances, because obviously OP knows how to set the thermostat or else it wouldn't heat up to the selected temperature. Therefore, it isn't working right. Which means **repair**. Which **IS ON TOPIC**.