# Gas oven is not holding temperature

Tags: repair, appliances, oven

My gas oven, Frigidare model FPGF3081KFM, does not always hold the correct temperature.  It will always ignite correctly initially and come up to the correct temperature, but for long cooking sessions (half an hour or more) it will occasionally stop heating entirely.  The interior will be cool to the touch despite being set to normal cooking temperatures.

I have already replaced the temperature sensor and the main (bottom) igniter element with brand new parts.

The gas burners on the stove top work correctly.  I have not smelled unburnt gas at any point.

This may be a duplicate of these previous questions, but neither had a satisfactory answer:

[Gas oven won't maintain temperature it is set on](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/179755/gas-oven-wont-maintain-temperature-it-is-set-on)

[Gas oven sometimes stops heating](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/gas-oven-sometimes-stops-heating)

Comment: Have you contacted Frigidaire? If you do and find an answer please answer your own question I am sure it will get upvoted since there are no real answers so far. Also posting your answer on the other questions may help those folks.

Comment: Next step is to replace the control board, since you now know the sensor & igniters are working correctly -- actually you knew this because the oven starts up and then stops when it reaches temperature.